# Unique key with all attributes?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, database-schema, unique-key

I have to store devices in my database, each device is unique.

Makes it sense to create a unique key with all the attributes ?

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE device (
    index_id            UNSIGNED MEDIUMINT  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    store_timestamp     TIMESTAMP           NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    imei                UNSIGNED BIGINT(15)                 
    software_id         VARCHAR(40)                     
    ip                  CHAR(15)                        
    wlan_mac_adress     CHAR(12)                        
    bluetooth_adress    CHAR(12)
    PRIMARY KEY (index_id)
    UNIQUE KEY (imei) 
    UNIQUE KEY (software_id, ip)
    UNIQUE KEY (wlan_mac_adress)
    UNIQUE KEY (bluetooth_adress)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Sometimes I will have null keys: For example, in iOS devices I can not get the imei or mac.

Comment: Multicolumn keys allow duplicating in some of the columns, but not all

Comment: Can you let us know how many records you expect to have?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I have updated the post. I exactly do not know how many record but lets say 2000-3000 aproximately. I considering to create a script to delete older records.

Comment: try to make unique key with combine these all columns imei,software_id,ip,wlan_mac_adress,bluetoot_adress

Comment: You have an auto-incremented primary key and unique constraints on the columns and combinations of columns that need them.  That looks quite reasonable.

Comment: IP CHAR(15) won't handle IPv6.  Need VARCHAR(39).  Is it defaulting to utf8?  If so, CHAR(10) takes 30 bytes unnecessarily since the value is probably simple ascii chars.  Add CHARACTER SET ascii.

Comment: I'm using ASCII for all the tables